# Can I filter a mongo query by virtual populates?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a parent reference relationship between a property model and a sale model. Within my sale model, I include a field to reference the parent property:

```js
property: {
   type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
   ref: "Property",
   required: [true, "Sale must belong to a property"],
}
```

At the end of my sale model, I include a mongoose pre find middleware to populate the name of the referenced property so that it can be filtered by in the query:

```js
saleSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: "property",
    select: "propInfo.propName",
  });
  next();
});
```

I would like to submit a request to my sales Router to return sales that have only applied to that property name:

```
{{URL}}api/v1/sales?property.propInfo.propName=SampleName
```

When I send a `getAll` request to `{{URL}}api/v1/sales` without any filters in the parameters, all of the property names will be populated in the response.

However, whenever I try to filter or query by the virtual populated property name, it will not return anything. It seems as if Mongo is populating the fields of the parent property after the query, even though I have a pre find middleware to populate the virtuals.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question but common misconception. Unfortunately, the `pre` hook in this case *attaches* the `populate` method to the `find` method. As a result, you cannot query the populated fields as they will not be be added until after the query executes.

With mongoose `populate` you cannot filter parent documents based on query conditions of child documents. This is one of the limitations.

Thankfully, mongoose models have the `Model.aggregate()` method where this kind of thing is pretty straightforward.

In the example below I have assumed you have `sales` collection and a `properties` collection based on your `Sale` and `Property` model names. I have also included some extra random fields such as `name` just for illustration.

1. `$lookup`: this is the same as `populate` where a lookup is done against the `properties` colletion to match the `Sale.property` field against the `Property._id` field.
2. `$unwind`: turn the array from `$lookup` into an object.
3. `$match`: now you can query the `propName` with your `SampleName`
4. `$project`: only output the fields you want.

```js
const sales = await Sale.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "properties",
      localField: "property",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "property"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$property"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "property.propInfo.propName": SampleName
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "name": 1,
      "property.propInfo.propName": 1
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/81Ah6SpkY0p) for a working example with some test data.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer. Do you think it would be worth embedding the sales within the properties instead? My concern with embedding is that the property document could become to large. I was also thinking of adding other collections such as leases, loans, contracts, and renovations, which could grow pretty large especially if I am working with a large property.

I also want a user to be able to query each of those collections by the parent property characteristics, so I'm not sure if creating a bunch of aggregate pipelines would become too confusing.

Comment: Having sub-documents embedded will indeed make it easier to query but with the disadvantage of bloating the document, which has a 16MB limit. However, it takes a lot of data to reach 16MB so not something that happens often. If the relationships are 1-1 then embedded is a good option but if it's 1-many then using referenced docs is preferred. Having many aggregations is pretty common and is probably the most powerful part of the database. You can always query the other collection to get a list of `_id`s then pass those `_id` to an `$in` query but means hitting the db 2+ times. @KyleMarsh